# All Style Files are of kind STY 文件 in Finder

Tags: mac

Recently noticed that all .sty appear in the Finder of kind "STY 文件".  Now 文件 means "Wénjiàn", which is Chinese for "file".  Whats going on here?!  Catalina 10.15.7, texlive 2020.

[image: Finder Info]

Comment: Looks like the app (or OS?) has (partly) picked up zh instead of de as the interface display language. What does System Preferences, Language & Region say for Tex/Latex?

Comment: Region is Germany ... BTW: What app do you mean? And notice that *all* .sty-files are affected.

Comment: I have same issue with .sty and .cls files, which are listed in the lsr database as org.tug.tex and in Finder's Get Info shown as associated with TeXShop.app, whose language is already the System default - English! I se no way to use System Preferences to change the language for a type of file, just for an app.

Comment: Since Murray happens to use TeXShop and Micheal seems to use Alpha this seems to be something happening at th OS level.

Comment: Yes, looks OS-related. On the 'What app?' question, the apps in System Preferences, Language and Region, Apps are
"The list of apps you’ve set to use a language other than the default language." (https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlddb13d65/mac). I was thinking that some install that uses sty files applied the setting.